# Eclipse stdio.h error

Tags: c, eclipse

I just downloaded eclipse and made a new c project.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

It's giving me an error saying that stdio.h library is not found. How can I fix this so that my code runs and compiles?

I am running this on windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on your platform. It's likely that you don't even have a C compiler installed if this is happening. You can probably fix this by installing GCC, but the instructions will vary depending on your OS.

Comment: how do i get that? for windows

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have Eclipse CDT plugins installed? Go to "Help > Install New Software" and click on "already installed" link to see the list of installed features/plugins in your current installation. Look for "CDT" in this list. If not present then use the p2 repository URL given [here](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) in your "Install New Software" dialog to get it installed. You should be good to compile C/C++ projects after this.

Comment: Hello I see "CDT Common GDB Support" in there but my code still says unresolved inclusion next to stdio.h

Comment: In that case please follow the steps outlined by @Tom Dignan to get MinGW installed on your system. You probably are missing GCC compiler.

Comment: okay I installed the gcc compiler and I can compile the .c file from the command prompt but how do i add that to eclipse so that when i build and compile the program from there.. it works

Comment: Go to project properties, "C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols" tab, and verify your include path.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Wascana](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/wascana/) from your eclipse that packages mingw and msys